# Problems using RestSharp resources

Tags: c#, restsharp

I use a code of Imagga Image, but I get errors, and I don't understand them.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using RestSharp;

namespace ImaggaAPISample {
  public class ImaggaSampleClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      string apiKey = "my_apiKey";
      string apiSecret = "my_apiSecret";
      string image = "path_to_image";

      string basicAuthValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", apiKey, apiSecret)));

      var client = new RestClient("https://api.imagga.com/v2/tags");
      client.Timeout = -1; //CS1061 error, don't know this property...

      var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST); //error CS0117 on POST method, it don't know
      request.AddHeader("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", basicAuthValue));
      request.AddFile("image", image);

      IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); //CS0246 don't know the IRestResponse interface
      Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I downloaded the RestSharp library. I verified, and the download was successful...
I tried to download another RestSharp library, but it didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean you "downloaded the RestSharp library"? Just follow the guide on their site: https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#introduction, where they tell you exactly what to do, namely, run `dotnet add package RestSharp`.

Comment: I downloaded `RestSharp` library and `RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson` library, by NuGet Package Manager. The libraries are displayed in Dependencies/Frameworks

Comment: `RestClient` doesn't have a `Timeout` property. Which most likely means you're trying to use sample code that was built for some very old `RestClient` release - it's undergone some significant (breaking) changes in the last year or two. See https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restclient-and-options to start with.